# Angular 2 and later | Extract properties from json

Tags: json, angular

Consider the following json model:

```
{ 
   "idNumber": "8908904",
   "firstname": "John",
   "lastname": "Doe",
   "address": "12 Kent, Pluto, CBD, 67435"
}
```

Is there a way in which I may read only the properties from this json model?

Expected output:

```
[ "idNumber", "firstname", "lastname", "address" ]
```

Comment: your expected output is not a valid javascript object.

Comment: If you only want to show it in the .html, In Angular 6 you have KeyValuePipe: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const json = { 
   "idNumber": "8908904",
   "firstname": "John",
   "lastname": "Doe",
   "address": "12 Kent, Pluto, CBD, 67435"
};

json.entries = Object.keys(json);
```

Is what you are looking for, it will return exact the same array you are expecting

*UPDATE:*
You can't store an array in Object without a key, so you probably will need to assign this array to a new key in here like the above and the output will be like this:

```
{ 
   "idNumber": "8908904",
   "firstname": "John",
   "lastname": "Doe",
   "address": "12 Kent, Pluto, CBD, 67435",
   "entries": ["idNumber", "firstname", "lastname", "address"]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code -

```
let keyArray = Object.keys({ 
                 "idNumber": "8908904",
                 "firstname": "John",
                 "lastname": "Doe",
                 "address": "12 Kent, Pluto, CBD, 67435"
               });
let requiredResponse = {keyArray};
console.log(requiredResponse.keyArray)  //[ "idNumber", "firstname", "lastname", "address" ]
```